# Cannot read property 'RFC_2822' of undefined

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, error

Cannot read property 'RFC_2822' of undefined is getting problem in magento 2.0.4

i saw this error in console. following one more error.

> women-blue-jacket.html:912 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'RFC_2822' of undefined
>       at women-blue-jacket.html:912
>       at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
>       at Module.check (require.js:866)
>       at Module. (require.js:1113)
>       at require.js:132
>       at require.js:1156
>       at each (require.js:57)
>       at Module.emit (require.js:1155)
>       at Module.check (require.js:917)
>       at Module.enable (require.js:1143)
>
> price-box.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function
>       at price-box.js:21
>       at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
>       at Module.check (require.js:866)
>       at Module. (require.js:1113)
>       at require.js:132
>       at require.js:1156
>       at each (require.js:57)
>       at Module.emit (require.js:1155)
>       at Module.check (require.js:917)
>       at Module. (require.js:1113)

full error as above. in more details im using free theme
http://www.venustheme.com/theme/ves-fasony-free-magento2-theme/  .

i dont know is, theme specific error or some where magento error.
if this error comes,  my product image will not load. i tried lot to remove it but not works.

Answer (score 1):

Its most probably because jquery or jquery-ui is included twice in your theme.
For me it was in venus theme :  Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml file
, I removed below line:

```
<script src="jquery.js" />
```

credit goes to @Dmitry Fedyuk for this solution: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/5748